# What does "backworld" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

You can read the chapter where the word [was met](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Thus_Spake_Zarathustra/Part_One#3._Backworldsmen). And I put a little extract below:

> To me the convalescent would it now be suffering and torment to believe in such phantoms: suffering would it now be to me, and humiliation. Thus I speak to **backworldsmen**.
>   Suffering was it, and impotence - that created all **backworlds**; and the short madness of happiness, which only the greatest sufferer experienceth.
>   Weariness, which seeketh to get the ultimate one leap, with a death-leap; a poor ignorant weariness, unwilling even to will any longer: that created all gods and **backworlds**.

There is also a derived word "backworldsmen". I guess the world is author-invented? Could you shed some light on its meaning?

Comment: This is vague. Can you give more details? Can you give a quote in context?

Comment: Sorry, added some info.

Comment: This question might be more readily answerable at [philosophy.SE](philosophy.stackexchange.org). They would know better the interplay between Nietzsche's intentions, his wordplay, and the English translation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google does give results for *Thus spake Zarathustra backworld*. The first one is http://nathanbauman.com/odysseus/?p=2949

The first paragraph of that page says (my emphases):

> Zarathustra’s next two speeches in Nietzsche’s book *Thus Spake Zarathustra* are related in terms of their assertion that the physical world trumps the **Otherworld**, or, rather, the “backworld” as Del Caro translates the German term Hinterweltlern. **The term is very difficult to pin down in English.** The footnote to the word in my edition says that it refers to “those who are of, or believe in, a world beyond, a hidden or a back-world, **a secret world**”; the note also says, rather curiously, that the word has similar connotations to the English word hinterland. I think what is happening is that Zarathustra is saying that those who believe in an Otherworld are being provincial and silly.

This isn't a [German-language site](https://german.stackexchange.com/) so attempting to translate the German *Hinterwelt* and *Hinterweltlern* is not going to be easy. "Back-world" and "back-worlds-men" are the literal translations.

But the expression **other-worldly** does exist in English: "belonging or relating to, or resembling, a world supposedly inhabited after death" [Chambers], or perhaps "a world outside the physical realm."

Comment: I just found Russian translation of the book, and the translation of the word is no better. As I see, the book is very hard-to-translate because some words are quite ambigious or even neologisms. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the context I'm pretty sure "backworld" refers to the afterlife and "backworldsmen" are those who preach and believe in it.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing in the book’s context backworldsmen refers to people operating in a world other than the closest approximation to the objective one...

Answer (score 0):

He explains later in the book that the earth, like men, has a backside. Assuming from that backworlds is the rump of the earth.

Comment: This would benefit from a citation.  Hopefully a good find!

Answer (score -2):

"Backworld" seems to be an American folk-music group, a computer game, etc.

[image]

Also, a made-up English word to translate Nietzsche's German word "Hinterweltern".

**added**

The German "Hinterweltern" is not in my dictionary.  So either Neitzsche made it up or my dictionary is not complete enough.  There is a German word "Hinterwäldern", *backwoodsmen*, and this new word is made by replacing "Wald" *woods* with "Welt" *world*.

Comment: And do you know the meaning of the German word? Or could you guess it?

Comment: There is also "hinterland" meaning the more remote parts of a country, particularly a little-explored part of a continental rather than an island country. This is a loan word in English from the German "hinterland" with the same meaning.